# GridGain network connection: Is it possible to forward a node via SSH?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, gridgain

I would like to SSH into a remote machine running a gridgain instance and connect to it from a local gridgain instance. Can this be done?

How is the gridgain network connection being done? As far as I could sse the node spins up and listens on the first available port on 47100-47200. But it opens some more ports too.

It seems not be sufficient to just e.g. forward 47100 on the remote machine (the remote machines gridgain port) to local 47100. Probably the communication is not just client server but symmetrical with the remote node trying to connect to my home node?

*Is there documentation on the network protocol?*

---

I tried a symetrically forwarding the

- GridTcpCommunicationSpi.DFLT_PORTs (47100+) and
- GridTcpDiscoverySpi.DFLT_PORTs (47500+)

ports.

The nodes are able to connect. On the local node I first get this warning:

```
WARN  GridTcpCommunicationSpi - Connect timed out (consider increasing 'connTimeout' configuration property) [addr=/10.240.136.167:47100]
WARN  GridTcpDiscoverySpi - Timed out waiting for message delivery receipt (most probably, the reason is in long GC pauses on remote node; consider tuning GC and increasing 'ackTimeout' configuration property). Will retry to send message with increased timeout. Current timeout: 5000.
WARN  GridDhtPreloader - <gg-utility-sys-cache> Failed to wait for initial partition map exchange. Possible reasons are: 
  ^-- Transactions in deadlock.
  ^-- Long running transactions (ignore if this is the case).
  ^-- Unreleased explicit locks.
WARN  GridTcpDiscoverySpi - Timed out waiting for message to be read (most probably, the reason is in long GC pauses on remote node. Current timeout: 5000.
```

This is a timeout when somehow trying to connect to connect to 10.240.136.167:47100 - which is the remote machines local IP, which is obviously impossible.

But it looks nice as I get the following:

```
INFO  GridDiscoveryManager - Topology snapshot [ver=2, nodes=2, CPUs=6, heap=2.7GB]
```

On executing the following broadcast test:

```
        grid.compute().broadcast(new GridRunnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("hello!");
            }
        });
```

I get this fatal error on the remote machine, whatever it may be:

```
[SEVERE][gridgain-#9%pub-null%][GridJobProcessor] Task was not deployed or was redeployed since task execution [taskName=nix.GoogleGridRun$Test, taskClsName=at$
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:1732)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:654)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1800(GridIoManager.java:62)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$6.body(GridIoManager.java:615)
        at org.gridgain.grid.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:151)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[19:58:02,237][SEVERE][gridgain-#11%pub-null%][GridJobProcessor] Task was not deployed or was redeployed since task execution [taskName=nix.GoogleGridRun$1, taskClsName=at.a$
For more information see:
    Troubleshooting:      http://bit.ly/GridGain-Troubleshooting
    Documentation Center: http://bit.ly/GridGain-Documentation

class org.gridgain.grid.GridDeploymentException: Task was not deployed or was redeployed since task execution [taskName=nix.GoogleGridRun$1, taskClsName=at.ac.ait.is.infrase$
For more information see:
    Troubleshooting:      http://bit.ly/GridGain-Troubleshooting
    Documentation Center: http://bit.ly/GridGain-Documentation

        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1107)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:1732)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:654)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1800(GridIoManager.java:62)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$6.body(GridIoManager.java:615)
```

On the client side I don't see anything but:

```
INFO  GridDeploymentLocalStore - Class locally deployed: class nix.GoogleGridRun$1
hello!
```

When I try to push the broadcast again via the debugger, then I get the following on the local machine and the same error message as before on the remote machine:

```
ERROR GridTaskWorker - Failed to obtain remote job result policy for result from GridComputeTask.result(..) method (will fail the whole task): GridJobResultImpl [job=o.g.g.kernal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$10@7e89183d, sib=GridJobSiblingImpl [sesId=4c17983b841-43f8b9fa-87ae-4a20-99a1-8d36f5eb74a4, jobId=0d17983b841-ef0084a6-f6a7-4501-87a0-3c5eb7c72bca, nodeId=ef0084a6-f6a7-4501-87a0-3c5eb7c72bca, isJobDone=false], jobCtx=GridJobContextImpl [jobId=0d17983b841-ef0084a6-f6a7-4501-87a0-3c5eb7c72bca, attrs={}], node=GridTcpDiscoveryNode [id=ef0084a6-f6a7-4501-87a0-3c5eb7c72bca, addrs=[10.240.136.167, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.240.136.167:47500, /10.240.136.167:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, loc=false, ver=6.5.0#20140925-sha1:6dc3d773], ex=class o.g.g.GridDeploymentException: Task was not deployed or was redeployed since task execution [taskName=nix.GoogleGridRun$Test, taskClsName=nix.GoogleGridRun$Test, codeVer=0, clsLdrId=eb17983b841-43f8b9fa-87ae-4a20-99a1-8d36f5eb74a4, seqNum=1411761402302, depMode=SHARED, dep=null]
For more information see:
    Troubleshooting:      http://bit.ly/GridGain-Troubleshooting
    Documentation Center: http://bit.ly/GridGain-Documentation
, hasRes=true, isCancelled=false, isOccupied=true]
class org.gridgain.grid.GridException: Remote job threw user exception (override or implement GridComputeTask.result(..) method if you would like to have automatic failover for this exception).
    at org.gridgain.grid.compute.GridComputeTaskAdapter.result(GridComputeTaskAdapter.java:109)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$3.apply(GridTaskWorker.java:819)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$3.apply(GridTaskWorker.java:812)
    at org.gridgain.grid.util.GridUtils.wrapThreadLoader(GridUtils.java:6093)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.result(GridTaskWorker.java:812)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.onResponse(GridTaskWorker.java:708)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.processJobExecuteResponse(GridTaskProcessor.java:906)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$JobMessageListener.onMessage(GridTaskProcessor.java:1138)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:654)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1800(GridIoManager.java:62)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$6.body(GridIoManager.java:615)
    at org.gridgain.grid.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:151)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: class org.gridgain.grid.GridDeploymentException: Task was not deployed or was redeployed since task execution [taskName=nix.GoogleGridRun$Test, taskClsName=nix.GoogleGridRun$Test, codeVer=0, clsLdrId=eb17983b841-43f8b9fa-87ae-4a20-99a1-8d36f5eb74a4, seqNum=1411761402302, depMode=SHARED, dep=null]
For more information see:
    Troubleshooting:      http://bit.ly/GridGain-Troubleshooting
    Documentation Center: http://bit.ly/GridGain-Documentation

    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1107)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:1732)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:654)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1800(GridIoManager.java:62)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$6.body(GridIoManager.java:615)
    at org.gridgain.grid.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:151)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

On the local host side I have connections between the virtual and real ports

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:47100         127.0.0.1:38272         VERBUNDEN   12280/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:38272         127.0.0.1:47100         VERBUNDEN   12280/java
```

And some more to and from the ssh client (also java)

```
tcp6   45832      0 78.101.12.107:47101    146.148.119.62:51867    VERBUNDEN   12280/java      
tcp6     231      0 78.101.12.107:47501    146.148.119.62:46219    CLOSE_WAIT  12280/java      
tcp6      48      0 78.101.12.107:37129    146.148.119.62:22       VERBUNDEN   12280/java   
tcp6       1      0 78.101.12.107:47501    146.148.119.62:44391    CLOSE_WAIT  12280/java
```

78.101.12.107 = local ip
146.148.119.62 = remote ip

I looked at netstat on a successful local 2 node grid I see the following connections being made:

```
tcp6       0      0 ::1:47501               ::1:43143               VERBUNDEN   10218/java      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:47500               ::1:34708               VERBUNDEN   9496/java       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:34708               ::1:47500               VERBUNDEN   10218/java      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:43143               ::1:47501               VERBUNDEN   9496/java
```

These are between the GridTcpCommunicationSpi.DFLT_PORTs and GridTcpDiscoverySpi.DFLT_PORTs - so these should maybe be enough.

*Any Ideas on what could be wrong?*

Answer (score 0):

Home node should be available from cluster as well. You have 2 options:

1. Setup VPN
2. Implement and configure GridAddressResolver for all nodes which will turn their local addresses to external addresses. This will require to setup port forwarding in your home network.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Well 1 was obvious, when thee is a VPN then there is a PN to GridGain. What do you mean by 2? I could make GridGain believe, that a node is on a remote address even though it is "virtually local"? When using a tunnel then it is one way only. I could as well set up a back route port forwarding. Then I suppose, the port numbers would have to be the same on both machines for one two-way connection, as none of the machines probably knows which machine they are on. Is there docs on the ports GridGain needs? Is it only one?

Comment: I now pretty much get what you maybe mean by 2. I could change the address a node is connected to at. But what about a node on "localhost" - which is the ssh tunnel scenario? I think I will have to do some debugging unless somebody knows more.